# How can I check the distribution for gender separately when the data is not separated by gender?

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I have to check if the data has a normal distribution for CREANZ for male and female, but my dataset has the genders mixed up and I don't how to separate them so that I can check the distribution for the genders separately. I did the following before:

```
df$Gender[df$Gender=="V"]=0.742
df$Gender[df$Gender=="M"]=1
df$Gender[df$Gender=="F"]=0.742
df$Gender<-as.numeric(df$Gender)
df$Gender<-as.numeric(df$Gender)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at reproducible examples if you want to get more answers.

You can check normality both with plots and tests. If you want a test, shapiro wilk may be a good choice. Using pipelines:

```
df %>%
   dplyr::select(CREANZ, gender) %>%
   group_by(gender) %>%
   summarise(across(.fns = ~shapiro.test(.))) -> result
```

and if you just want the p-value

```
df %>%
   dplyr::select(CREANZ, gender) %>%
   group_by(gender) %>%
   summarise(across(.fns = ~shapiro.test(.)$p.value)) -> result
```